# Background-color property isn't working on Sticky Navigation bar with a Dropdown list

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner and trying to code a **sticky navigation bar with a dropdown menu.** The problem I am facing is that I have to remove **overflow: hidden** property for enabling the dropdown list, however after removing **overflow: hidden property** dropdown list works fine but the **background-color**property of the navigation bar gets disabled.

```css
 ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: black;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 1;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }

        li {

            float: left;
        }

        li a,
        .dropbutton {
            display: inline-block;
            color: rgb(230, 11, 11);
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            max-width: 80px;
        }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: red;
            color: black;
        }

        li.dropdown {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: black;
            max-width: inherit;
            z-index: 1;
            max-width: auto;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            display: block;
            color: rgb(241, 22, 22);
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: left;
        }


        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: white;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 30px;
            text-shadow: 15px 15px 22px grey;
            color: rgb(202, 23, 23);
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;

        }

        .world {
            font-size: 40px;
            text-shadow: 15px 15px 22px grey;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

```html
  <h1 class="world">Hello world</h1>
    <h1>Fixed Navigation Bar with Dropdown</h1>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Home">Blogs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Home">News</a></li>
        <li style="float: right;"><a href="#Search">Search</a>
        <li style="float: right;"><a href="#Switch">Switch</a>
        <li class="dropdown" style="float: right;"><a class="dropbutton" href="#Home">Settings</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#Account">Account</a>
                <a href="#Notification">Notification</a>
                <a href="#Password">Password</a>
                <a href="#Lougout">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <br>
    <br><br>
    <p>Sample text for enable scrolling</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
    <p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` instead of overflow:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(230, 11, 11);
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 80px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  max-width: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: auto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(241, 22, 22);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: 15px 15px 22px grey;
  color: rgb(202, 23, 23);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.world {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 15px 15px 22px grey;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="world">Hello world</h1>
<h1>Fixed Navigation Bar with Dropdown</h1>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Home">Blogs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Home">News</a></li>
  <li style="float: right;"><a href="#Search">Search</a>
    <li style="float: right;"><a href="#Switch">Switch</a>
      <li class="dropdown" style="float: right;"><a class="dropbutton" href="#Home">Settings</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#Account">Account</a>
          <a href="#Notification">Notification</a>
          <a href="#Password">Password</a>
          <a href="#Lougout">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </li>

</ul>
<br>
<br><br>
<p>Sample text for enable scrolling</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
<p>This is a test run of fixed navigation bar</p>
```

Comment: Great! it works fine.. Could you please explain why it wasn't working with overflow property?

Comment: @BhupenderSoni because overflow:hidden will *hide* everything outside the element thus you cannot see the dropdown. I used inline-block that will have the same effect (clear your float) and it won't hide any overflow

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I am more clear with my mind.